# Dynamic Array of flash AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I have an array to store true answers and false answer of random frame multiple choices questions:

**var arraytruefalseanswer=[];**

I use **push** method to insert every true and false answer in the array:

**arraytruefalseanswer.push(trueanswer)**

**arraytruefalseanswer.push(falseanswer)**

The problem is:
I can not remove the last element of **arraytruefalseanswer** .

Because
If I use *pop* method **arraytruefalseanswer.pop()**,
it will remove all elements in the array **arraytruefalseanswer** or bring back to
**arraytruefalseanswer=[]**

If i use delete, it is still leaving null.

Please help... how can I remove the last element of **arraytruefalseanswer** using flash AS3?
Thank you.

Comment: **(1)** You can try updating your array like `myArray = myArray.pop();` **(2)** These are your [**Array** options](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#methodSummary). Try using **slice** _(startPos, endPos)_ like `myArray.slice(0, (myArray.length-1) );` or try using **removeAt** _(Pos)_ like `myArray.removeAt( myArray.length - 1);`... where that `myarray` is your own array's name and is also updated against itself like in step **1**.

Comment: I've found the answer using visibility method. Thank you for the help so far... n good luck.

Comment: How does visibility remove item from an array? Also no-one can answer cos you put too much code, why not just show us code of a simple test (make array, put 3 things and show us how you try remove the last thing from that array and we help you to fix). When you know then you use knowledge in your long code.

Comment: Also I still wonder about this line `if(XXX1jumlahbenar1_41BMID1 == XXX1jumlahbenar1_41BMID1++)` ... What does it do when it `++` an array? ... You can't say `if( myArray == myArray++) { do something };` .. Finally Please put your content inside a MovieClip then travel in those frames like `myMC.gotoAndStop(x)` because just using `gotoAndStop(x)` alone makes the whole **Stage** change frames and you will have errors if your code tries to control something not existing in that frame.

Comment: "XXX1jumlahbenar1_41BMID1" is a var dynamic text to store the right answer. When clicking the true answer it will add 1 score and the array "myArray" will store "1" as the element in the array. when we don't know and still doubtful with the answer we want to change another answer. Then we click review button. And i want This review button to remove the last element of the array... as i think the only way is using pop() delete, ect. Program still running But giving other result. So, i have an idea why i don't try to manipulating button using visible true and false... and as a result, it works.

Comment: And i from my deep inside say thankyou very much for your kindness helping me.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation says](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#pop()): When you do a `pop()`, it returns items that were popped, and the array gets modified as a side effect. Therefore, in order to just remove the last element, you call `arraytruefalseanswer.pop();` as is. You can use `trace(arraytruefalseanswer)` to verify if anything popped. Also check your code flow, it's possible that when you're popping your last element, you think the code reaches the call once but it's not so, and it say pops your entire array so you've left with an empty array. I can't say more without ever seeing your entire block of code where you work eith your `truefalseanswer`.

Comment: I've found the answer using visibility method. Thank you for the help so far... n good luck.

Comment: @AndiWidodo So you ended up having a XY problem - you claim you have a problem that `pop()` deletes the array, in reality the code that tries to pop does not have a valid link to the array. OK, at least this helped you to debug the problem.

Comment: Yeah.. that time the only way was removing the last element of the array as i think the simplest way...so i tried pop, delete removeAt, splice, slice... From one to another... but no result. Then i tried using visibility and right it is a long way to finish... because it gives side effect to other frames.